# Azure active directory

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory, authorization

I have a client-server application which could be deployed on azure. When somebody try to connect to azure server to use this app I need to know is this user in my AD or not. Before establish connection to server user types password and login which are sent to server in connection request. Thank you for help.

Comment: Check out ACS  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/

Comment: For information on how to use OAuth in your application see this link: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/09/12/active-directory-authentication-library-adal-v1-for-net-general-availability/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're targeting AD, [Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/identity/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it without AD?

Comment: Do you mean is there an alternative way to authorize against your existing AD server w/o using Windows Azure Active Directory?

Or are you asking about other authorization mechanisms besides AD?

Comment: About other authorization mechanisms

Comment: If you're looking to move away from AD, maybe you could consider OAuth? With OAuth you also get out of the business of storing user creds which is a nice security benefit.

Comment: As I know OAuth work only with ASP.net. I'm not writing a website. It's .not application with own client part.

Answer (score 0):

You can Integrate using ADFS - ACS - WIF. This will give local AD user to access your cloud application. For more information see [this whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13789).